# Reloadable visa scam

Tags: scams

So, I had someone message me. Then have me buy a reloadable visa. Set it up. Sent the card info then I got an email from [*scam site redacted*] stating I have had a new account made for me with some money and I’m order to access the funds I need to buy an Apple Card $200-$400 or to get Bitcoin in order to use the access code to gain access to the money in the account and to gain account approval. Is that a scam? Seems like one to me.

Comment: Why would you follow any sort of instructions from "someone" who messaged you?  Whatever money you have spent in this scam is lost, get over it!  Any additional money  you spend on this will also be lost.  STOP NOW!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, obviously that is a scam.